# insert multipyle rows into sqlite database with PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, pyqt5

So far I can insert the input from `QLineEdit` into a database with

```
self.add_to_db_button.clicked.connect(self.add_userinput)


 def add_userinput(self):
        self.query = qsql.QSqlQuery()
        self.query.prepare("INSERT INTO userinput(firstcolumns) VALUES(?)")
        self.query.addBindValue(self.user_input.text())
        self.query.exec()
        self.close
```

with this code a can ad a row in my db

how can I  insert the input from multiple `QLineEdit` into my db, starting at a empty row in the columnn?
for example:

```
 self.query.addBindValue(self.schale1_input.text())
        self.query.addBindValue(self.input_1.text())
        self.query.addBindValue(self.input_2.text())
        self.query.addBindValue(self.input_3.text())
        self.query.addBindValue(self.input_4.text())
```

I know that I need to use `next()` from the `QSqlQuery Class` to switch to another row
But so far I dont know how to execute it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the pyside2 docs

I needed to use `BatchExecutionMode` to insert multiple values

in the docs is an example too

[PySide2 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlQuery.html#PySide2.QtSql.PySide2.QtSql.QSqlQuery.addBindValue)